# Trying to get all records of a generic list using Sharepoint and Microsoft Graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to get records of a list in SharePoint i keep getting Response like:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('123')/sharepoint/sites('456')/lists('789')/items","value":[]}
```

I was able to run through all sites and lists but still fail on items. The list has the GenericList template. However on another list with the template DesignCatalog i were able to get all items. Is "/items" the wrong way to get records of a generic list?

Here is a snippet of my current Code:

```
            const string serviceEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var token = await _authenticationHelper.GetTokenAsync();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            // get the site
            HttpResponseMessage responseGetSites = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(serviceEndpoint + "sharePoint:/Intranet"));
            if (responseGetSites.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await responseGetSites.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jResult = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                siteItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteItemModel>(jResult.ToString());

                // get all lists with the given site id
                HttpResponseMessage responseGetLists = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(serviceEndpoint + "sharepoint/sites/" + siteItem.SiteId + "/lists"));
                if (responseGetLists.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseContent2 = await responseGetLists.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var jResult2 = JObject.Parse(responseContent2);

                    foreach (JObject listresponse in jResult2["value"])
                    {
                        ListItemModel desiralizedItemModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListItemModel>(listresponse.ToString());
                        listItemCollection.Add(desiralizedItemModel);
                    }

                    // find a specific list
                    string listId = listItemCollection.Where(w => w.listName == "MyTestlist").First().listId;

                    // get all records with of the given list
                    HttpResponseMessage responseGetItems = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(serviceEndpoint + "sharepoint/sites/" + siteItem.SiteId + "/lists/" + listId + "/items"));
                    if (responseGetItems.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string responseContent3 = await responseGetItems.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var jResult3 = JObject.Parse(responseContent3);
```

Comment: Which permissions is your app requesting? Do the authenticated user have permissions for the site?

Comment: The user has admin permission for the site. Additionaly the app has delegated permissions like "sign in and read user profile" on the Microsoft graph api. But i also tried all "non admin requierd" permission on the graph and SharePoint api

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to add "Sites.ReadWrite.All" permission under MS Graph, not under sharepoint (I was writing to the list as well, but "Sites.Read.All" should work).